# JavaScript. Почему данный код не выдает задуманное число?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, task

Не судите строго мой код, я новичок в js, хотел бы понять в чём была моя ошибка. Было бы классно услышать еще и объяснения. Задача: 'Составить функцию, которая вернёт самое маленькое чётное число в массиве, в массиве оно обязательно есть!'. Проблема: 'Код не работает:( Возвращает 1, как я понимаю это индекс, то есть число 3. И еще вопрос: Math.min() - возвращает индекс?'. Снизу будет мой код =>

```js
let input = [4, 3, 20, 6, 8];

function oge(int) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < int.length; i++) {
    count = Math.min(int[i] % 2 === 0);
  }

  return count;
};
console.log(oge(input));
```

Comment: `int[i] % 2 === 0` выражение имеет значение true или false, ну а `Math.min(true|false)` может возвращать только 1 или 0 соответственно. Вы перезаписываете переменную count в каждой итерации, поэтому будет сохранён только результат последней итерации. Смотрим на последнюю итерацию: `int[i]` это 8, `8 % 2 === 0` это true, `Math.min(true)` это 1, поэтому эта функция будет всегда возвращать 1

Comment: Math.min возвращает не индекс. Откуда вообще такая мысль??? Использовать функции, не зная, что они делают, не очень хорошая идея.   Добавьте в свой массив в конце число 7, например, и посмотрите на результат.

Comment: А вообще задача решается в одну строку `const oge = (int) => Math.min(...int.filter((x) => x % 2 === 0));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.min` возвращает(и принимает) то что написано в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

```js
let input = [4, 3, 20, 6, 8]

function oge(arrInt) {
  let min = Infinity
  for (let int of arrInt) {
    if (int % 2 === 0 && int < min) min = int
  }
  return min === Infinity ? undefined : min
}
console.log(
  oge(input)
)

// Вариант с Math.min и filter
console.log(
  Math.min(...input.filter((int) => (int % 2 === 0)))
)
```